# Switch Source Vs. Sink Modes with USB PD over type c

Tags: linux, power-management, acpi

I have a [60W type C battery pack](https://www.ravpower.com/products/rp-pb201-pd-60w-20000mah-portable-charger) and I can use to charge my laptop. It is designed to both accept power and send power over its single USB C port. However, since the type c ports on my laptop are also able to both supply and accept power, the behavior of the battery pack when plugged in is inconsistent. Most often, when I plug in the battery pack, the laptop decides to supply power to the battery, which is often not what my intent is. However, it does sometimes go the other way, with the battery supplying power to the laptop as expected. I am running ArcoLinux with kernel version 5.16.3 on my [Framework laptop](https://frame.work/products/laptop-diy-edition).

I did look into the response posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1485990) to a question from about 4 years ago, which suggested I could switch this mode in the file at `/sys/class/typec/port0/power_role`. However, while the directory under `/sys/class/typec` exists on my device, that directory seems to be empty, containing no ports at all, let alone information about their power roles. I also know that this particular port on my laptop *does* work to accept power (as well as all 4 ports on the device) as it all works fine when using a more traditional power brick.

Is there some way I can change this power mode on the fly so that I could write a script or something to have an easy way to change if the port is supplying or accepting power?

Comment: Have found a solution eventually? On my machine I do have `/sys/class/typec/port0/power_role` but when I try to change it from source to sink I get "Invalid argument" error

Comment: @ZaarHai, I have not found a solution so far, no. Let me know if you come up with something!

Comment: I have the same RAVPower PB201 on Kernel 6.1.8 and posted a bunch of comments on https://superuser.com/a/1485990/30982 about my attempts at getting this working too. However, most often for me the bank supplies power to the laptop, and I want the laptop to supply power to the bank. For me it does this 100% of the time. I haven't had success yet. I am thinking a good next step would be to post to the Linux Kernel Mailing List.